# Run Selenium Unit Tests in Azure Without CI/CD?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, selenium, unit-testing, azure-devops

I have a set of Selenium WebDriver tests that work okay on three different machines; unfortunately, they don't seem to work consistently on a mentor's machine.  I'm not sure if I coded the WebDriverWait conditions poorly, or if there is just something odd with my mentor's machine.

I need a consistent environment to run the unit tests in that is friendly for all developers on my team.  We have a few test servers at our disposal, but some of our developers prefer to work on local boxes.  Most of our developers should have access to Azure Devops, but they tend to prefer to use an in-house solution for CM.

Is there a way for me force my unit tests to run in Azure without having to setup a CI/CD pipeline?  If I do that, will the Visual Studio subscribers on my team incur billing charges from Microsoft each time they run my unit tests?

**NOTEs:**

1. I can probably setup a CI/CD pipeline for our own in-house CM solution to run the unit tests, but our in-house CM solution is not necessarily Microsoft friendly and my organization's slot for a CI/CD expert is currently empty
2. I didn't readily notice how to run unit tests in Azure without CI/CD during Bing and Google searches

Comment: No. CI is the appropriate tool for this job. You should use it.

Comment: Docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is NO. The Azure Pipelines supports automatically build and test of code projects to make them available to others. It works with just about any language or project type. Azure Pipelines combines continuous integration (CI) and continuous delivery (CD) to constantly and consistently test and build your code and ship it to any target. I don't see other tools in Azure to run unit tests in Azure without pipeline.

Comment: I accept your answer; however, while looking around yesterday, I noticed there were posts by various authors about running unit tests inside a docker container.  That option may allow me to at least run the tests locally in a consistent environment even if I don't wind up using Azure and/or CI/CD.